# SQL query to find records matching

Tags: sql

Here is my table structure

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
===================
CompanyA   0
-----------------
CompanyA    1
-----------------
CompanyA    2
-----------------
CompanyB    0
-----------------
CompanyC    0
-----------------
CompanyC    1
-----------------
```

I want to return only records which has ColumnB=0 , but it should not return ColumnA records where values are "CompanyA" and "CompanyC", it should return only records with "CompanyB".

Comment: homework? Please read about the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table t
where t.ColumnB=0 and t.ColumnA='CompanyB'
```

Comment: here I dont know that columnA value is 'CompanyB' , i want records only by checking ColumnB values i.e columnA should not be in where clause

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alex, but here is a solution

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM   Table
WHERE  ColumnB = 0 AND ColumnA = 'CompanyB'
```

Comment: here I dont know that columnA value is 'CompanyB' , i want records only by checking ColumnB values i.e columnA should not be in where clause

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation.  I am guessing that you really want the companies whose max `columnB` is 0.  If so:

```
select columnA
from t
group by columnA
having max(columnB) = 0;
```

Comment: yes you are right ... I want only those companies where columnB value is 0 only (i.e if it has 1,2 along with 0 it should not return that record)

Comment: @Roger . . . You could explain that better in the question.